# Varnish 4.1 - Call a restart according to the backend response

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

Prior to Varnish 4, One could call a restart from vcl_fetch to start another flow reaching vcl_recv.

In version 4, logic was separated to client and backend, I need to be able to call a restart according to the backend response. One direction I thought might be possible is using vcl_synth as a middleware between backend and client but the backend can't send a specific error code or msg only standard 503 error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot restart a request during `vcl_backend_*` in Varnish 4.x.

You could `return (abandon)` during `vcl_backend_*` and then restart the request in `vcl_synth` if `resp.status == 503`, but you cannot transport any information from `vcl_backend_*` to `vcl_synth` in order to implement a smarter conditional.

As an alternative, you could execute the restart during `vcl_deliver` based on whatever was returned by the backend side.